# String replace *./*: with nothing, using variable passed to batch file from command line

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, variable-expansion

I am ripping my hair out. Why can't there be a debugger made available for batch scripting?

First step of my current batch script (and it does have to be in this "language", as I don't have c/wscript able to be used) is simply to remove the hour portion of (what was originally an argument in the format 1:10, that has recently been changed to try an hour+minute separator character that isn't the same as the delimiter for `set` replacement of part of a string), so that I can also get the minute portion of the argument. I have so far tried:

1. Delayed expansion - `set ShutdownMinute2762=!ShutdownTime2762:*.=!`
2. Various versions of standard expansion (as some remembered examples):

   i. `set ShutdownMinute2762=%ShutdownTime2762:*.=%`
   ii. `set ShutdownMinute2762=%%ShutdownTime2762%:*.=%`
   iii. `set ShutdownMinute2762=%%%ShutdownTime2762%:*.=%%`
3. Escaping both the `*` & the `.` in the `call set` versions, with `^`'s
4. [As below] Storing the argument in another variable at script launch
5. Setting the `ShutdownTime2762` variable in the script, not through the argument
6. [As below] - Using `call set`

   ```
   setlocal

   set ShutdownTime2762=%1

   call set ShutdownMinute2762=%%ShutdownTime2762:*.=%%
   call set ShutdownHour2762=%%ShutdownTime2762:%ShutdownMinute2762%=%%

   echo.%ShutdownHour2762%
   echo.%ShutdownMinute2762%

   endlocal
   ```

*Provided Input:* `1.10`
*Expected Output:*
`1`
`10`

With every. single. run. after. every. single. change. both `%ShutdownHour2762%` & `%ShutdownMinute2762%` displays as empty. **What am I missing?**

Comment: Can you include a sample of expected input / desired output values?

Comment: @LotPings - Not so. In the first set I am looking to use the `*.` to represent everything up to and including the `.` are replaced with nothing (I really wish I could use `:` though, but if this complicates the code much, I will reneg to use the altered time format). The referenced question wants to use `*` in the literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would

```
for /f "tokens=1* delims=." %%a in ("%1") do set shutdownhour=%%a&set shutdownminute=%%b

echo %shutdownhour%
echo %shutdownminute%
```

Do what you want to do?

---

Using `set`:

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL

SET "var1=%1"
SET "var2=%var1:*.=%"
CALL set "var1=%%var1:.%var2%=%%"
SET var

GOTO :EOF
```

The `setlocal` ensures that any changes made to the environment are backed out when the procedure ends, so that changes don't accumulate from running multiple batches or repeating batches.

The first `set` assigns the first parameter from the command line to `var1` which, given a parameter of `1.10` should assign `1.10` to `var1`.

Adding `echo`es of the two variables used at this point should indeed yield no output for `var2` but should show `1.10` for `var1`.

The second `set` assigns all those characters in `var1` *except* the characters up to and including the first `.` to `var2`, so `var2` should acquire the value `10`.

The third `set` uses a `call` to invoke the parsing twice. The first substitutes the value of `var2`  (since *it* is between single `%`) and the second executes `set "var1=%var1:.10=%"` since the value of `var2` would be substituted into the command. This assigns `1` to `var1` since the `.10` is replaced by *nothing*.

the `set var` saves typing on `echo %var1% %var2%` since it lists the values of all variables starting `var`

The `set "var=value"` syntax I use habitually since it ensures that trailing spaces on the batch line are not included in the value assigned (which can be very hard to debug)

Comment: I'd use "%~1" in case of a quoted argument. This was my too slow answer ;-) +1

Comment: It looks like it would. While I will probably use this, given the time spent trying to get the format `set variableB=%variableA:*.=%` to work, could you possibly figure out how to use this format to get the desired result?

Comment: Thanks, but the `set` example doesn't appear to work. Introducing `echo.%var1%` and `echo.%var2%` in between each of the first 2 set's produces the command line argument, and then a line of blank output. I also can't understand what the final `set var` is for. Perhaps an explanation of how the code works might help track down the issue.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. `set var` use seems obvious now. However I think the problem all along was the (using your answers variable names) `set "var1=%1" \n if "%var1%" equ "" (...) else ( <code discussed above> )` I omitted, to simply the code in my example. Remove the if else and one gets the desired output. Keep it in and the output is blank, despite at the start of the `else` clause `echo %var1%` reporting that it is still filled with contents of `%1`?!?!?

Comment: Yo don't mention `if else` in your post. That's a whole new minefield...